# Can two multi-threaded object call two different stored procedures from a database?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, monitoring

This is my first message.

I am trying to create a windows service that have three tables which two of them are stores coordinates and the last one stores the address information came from google api. System have two threads calling a SP that call parameter values for posting data to google. Another SP is used for storing retrieved data. BUT i need to code my threads to use different SPs(doing the same work at all).

how can i code my thread class to behave differently from others? (one use SP1 and one use SP2 like)

Thanks..

Comment: Many threads in the same or different processes can call the same or different SPs in 1 or many databases but each thread must use a different connection. What others? What is the POST process?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. post process i mentioned was passing address to google API.like: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start two different threads each with their own threadstart function.  Don't start the threads using the same function.

Look at the example code here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx